# Zsh: Is there a way to show the line and source location of a function (similar to Bash's extdebug)?

Tags: shell, zsh

In Bash, if you do:

```
shopt extdebug
declare -F some_function
```

It will print out not only the source of the function, but also what file it's located in and what line it starts on, looking something like: `some_function 339 /Users/nate/.bash/functions`

However, I can't seem to find any equivalent in ZSH. Is it possible without to do without grepping?

The reason being, using third-party libs, a function could be coming from anywhere, and it's incredibly handy in tracking down issues if one of those functions is overwriting a builtin.

Hopefully it's just that my google-fu is weak.

Thanks :)

Comment: That would be nice, but I'm afraid that's not possible in Zsh. Anyway, something that might help: if your third-party libs autoload its functions (which I believe is a good practice) instead of sourcing everything, then you could look at your `$fpath` array, which contains a list of function search paths. Your autoload function comes from one of the paths.

Comment: On the particular issue of overwriting builtin: this one's easy. Just `which funcname`, and for builtins you'll get `funcname: shell built-in command`.

Comment: I couldn't find something that got *all* the way there, however, `whence -v function_name` will produce the function name and file it is contained in, however, it does not have the line number, I'm afraid.